# Как сделать рассылку сгруппированных фото в aiogram3?

Tags: aiogram

Пытаюсь сделать рассылку фотографий по пользователям, но когда отправляется группа фотографий, но бот отправляет фотографии очередями. Вот код, который имеется на данный момент:

```
@router.message(StateFilter(InputNews.news))
async def input_news(message: Message, state: FSMContext,bot: Bot):
    await state.update_data(news=message.text)
    count_user_ids_ = await count_user_ids()
    if message.content_type == ContentType.PHOTO:
        for count_user_id in count_user_ids_:
            await bot.send_photo(count_user_id, photo=message.photo[0].file_id,
                                 caption=message.caption)
            await asyncio.sleep(.05)
```